# Convert errno.h error values to Win32 GetLastError() equivalents

Tags: c++, winapi, posix, errno, dokan

[I'm writing](http://code.google.com/p/cpfs/) a layer between a [POSIX filesystem](http://www.tuxera.com/community/posix-test-suite/), and Windows using [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/), and need to convert error values of the [errno kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h) (`EINVAL`, `ENOENT`, etc.), to the Win32 equivalents you'd receive when calling [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(VS.85).aspx) (such as [`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=VS.85).aspx)).

**Is there an existing function, library, or reference I can use to perform these conversions?**

I typically poke through the Python source for inspiration on these matters, but Python neatly avoids this need (at least as far as I can tell).

As an example, `EINVAL (22)` would convert to `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had done an experiment about this subject in the past, mostly based on Microsoft [DOSMAP.CPP](http://pool.cern.ch/coral/currentReleaseDoc/doxygen/dosmap_8cpp-source.html) unit. However, I cancelled the project at that time because the error mapping was not always right for particular error codes. For Example, not every POSIX version return `EINVAL` for `ERROR_INVALID_ACCESS`, some of them return `EACCES` instead. I also had made a comparison between [errno.h system error numbers of POSIX.1-2008](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) and [DOSMAP.CPP](http://pool.cern.ch/coral/currentReleaseDoc/doxygen/dosmap_8cpp-source.html), [mingw.c](http://repo.or.cz/w/git/mingw.git/blame/15bf7ff5c74b0ef56b0fa4ab9f483399f9a20f35:/compat/mingw.c), [Postgresql error.c](http://anoncvs.postgresql.org/cvsweb.cgi/pgsql/src/backend/port/win32/Attic/error.c?rev=1.1&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup), [tclWinError.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-5/tcl/win/tclWinError.c), MySQL `my_winerr.c` and many more; sometimes, the mapping rule differ among them for particular error codes. Personally, I suggest you to deal with only the consistent error-code mapping among them.

Answer (score 8):

For each `errno` there are in general many possible `GetLastError` values, so what you're thinking may not necessarily be feasible.

Anyway, I just googled "errno to getlasterror", and the first google hit provided [this correspondence list](https://cygwin.com/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=winsup/cygwin/errno.cc;h=9168e9b4d965abf3e85b2015e879947096b9bbbd;hb=c874f1145ff5d2fa461cef21d6f8d575138fcdbf) from the Cygwin sources.

It is the wrong way, `GetLastError` to `errno`, but perhaps helpful?

Cheers & hth.