# How do I Represent Success Status Codes in Linux

Tags: c, linux, cross-platform

Windows has different types of status codes, `HRESULT` and `NTSTATUS` for instance, that allow for representing both success and failure values. This allows for macros like `FAILED` and `NT_SUCCESS`. One example of a success status code is `STATUS_PENDING` that indicates an IO is not yet complete.

I'm trying to map similar style status codes in Linux. I have a (WIP) cross platform library that uses the above type of status codes on Windows (user mode and kernel mode). I have my own "FAILED" macro that wraps the above macros. I need an equivalent for Linux for it all.

I've looked around and haven't found anything interesting/helpful. For any system/platform function (sockets, thread, locks) that might return and error, I need to make sure it is converted to the appropriate status code type. Windows has lots of helpers for things like this, but I'm not sure about Linux.

Psuedocode example:

```
MY_STATUS SendAsync(...) {
   ASYNC_OPERATION* Operation = MY_ALLOC(...)
   if (Operation == NULL) {
       return MY_OUT_OF_MEMORY_ERROR; // Error status
   }
   // Build the operation
   MY_STATUS Status = QueueOperation(Operation);
   if (MY_FAILED(Status)) {
       return Status;
   }
   return MY_STATUS_PENDING; // Success status
}
```

The caller should then be able to have the following code:

```
MY_STATUS Status = SendAsync(...)
if (MY_FAILED(Status)) {
   // Bail
}
// Handle success
```

I think the crux of the problem is that I don't know how to stuff status codes from system/platform function calls into a generic type that supports success/fail. Generally, it looks like all the status codes are positive, so I could just say my success error codes are `<= 0`. But I'm not sure that's a great solution.

To be clear, since it was proposed that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352922/in-windows-is-there-any-way-to-convert-an-errno-into-an-hresult) might the answer, I'm not trying to force the Linux status/error codes into `HRESULT` format explicitly. I'm just trying to find *some way* to represent error codes as either success or failure. If I have to convert system error codes (negate them?) along the way, that's acceptable. If there is no real solution to this problem, then that would be an acceptable answer (though not desired), and I'll have to find some work around.

Comment: Please explicitly include a problem statement (i.e. a question with a question mark) in your question.

Comment: @shellter That isn't necessary for this question. It's asking about something other than code that's not working.

Comment: Can you give us a few examples of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @JL2210 It's a cross platform network library, that both has it's own error codes (success and failure) and returns system error codes.

Comment: @NickBanks Any *specific* examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert errno.h error values to Win32 GetLastError() equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3952342/608639), [In Windows, is there any way to convert an errno into an HRESULT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12352922/608639), etc.

Comment: I also think you should  handle errors independently at the library level based on the OS results. That is, your application maps `Win32:ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` and `Linux:EACCES` to a library error like `MyLib:ACCESS_DENIED`. You can also map other types of errors, like `SQLite:SQLITE_PERM` into  `MyLib:ACCESS_DENIED`. I found that is cleanest based on a cross-platform library that supported Android, BSDs, iOS, Linux, OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **error codes** in linux there are the constants defined in errno.h header file. The error constants are available from man page `man 3 errno`. Also there is: [What errno means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503878/how-to-know-what-the-errno-means)

As for **exit status codes**, there is no standard set of codes. The value 0 has always denoting success, and non-zero value has denoted an error state. Bash, for example has this [Bash exit status information](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html).

> All of the Bash builtins return an exit status of zero if they succeed
>   and a non-zero status on failure, so they may be used by the
>   conditional and list constructs. All builtins return an exit status of
>   2 to indicate incorrect usage, generally invalid options or missing
>   arguments.

There is [sysexits](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits) which was an attempt to define a set of status codes, but it has been largely ignored in the field of linux software.

For more info: [Exit Status codes in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux)

Comment: So, bottom line, there isn't any clear definition of error codes in Linux? I'll just have to figure something out for my library?

Comment: *Error codes* , yes. Status codes, no. The full set of linux error codes are listed here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the error return code from a function in Linux, use the function's return value (usually nonzero on error) and the value of the `errno` variable, from `errno.h`.

Search for "linux errno codes" or run `man errno` on Linux to get more information.

`errno` (and return statuses) are usually represented as an `int`, so that's what I'd go with if you're looking for a type to use.

For example, checking to see if the return code of non-blocking `connect` is negative one and `errno` is `EINPROGRESS` is the same as checking for `STATUS_PENDING` in Windows.

Here's some pseudocode to respond to your pseudocode example:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
typedef /* Windows stuff */ MY_STATUS;
# define MY_FAILED(x) /* Windows stuff */
#else /* POSIX, other reasonable operating systems, etc. */
typedef int MY_STATUS;
# define MY_FAILED(x) ((x) == -1)
#endif
```

Of course, this assumes that your functions will return `int` or something similar, which may not be the case. But you get the idea.